# Ajax jquery on success return different html data in multiple divs:

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to return different data (html type) to different divs ?

```
 $.ajax({ 
        url: "file.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"html",
        data: {"id":id}
        }).done(function(data){ 
         $("#div1").html(data); 
         $("#div2").html(data); //how to do with a second div ?
        })
```

Comment: Your question in unclear, can you please explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

You can realize nested ajax requests like this:

```
$.ajax({
 url: form_url,
 type: form_method, 
 data: form_data, 
 cache: false, 
 success: function(data){ 
      $.ajax({
      url: form_url, 
      type: form_method, 
      data: form_data, 
      cache: false, 
      success: function(data){
        $("#div2").html(data);
      }
     }); 
 $("#div1").html(data);
 }
});
```

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hi, did this work? I'm looking for the same thing, data gets returned to the first div I have, but not the second?